# Error: Another app is currently holding the yum lock. al instalar programa en centos 6.5

Tags: centos6

Error surge al instalar vsftpd y muestra un mensaje indefinidamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿porque surge ese tipo de error :v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error se soluciona siguiendo los siguientes pasos.

1. Ubicar código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. ejecutar lo siguiente

```
rm -f /var/run/yum.pid 3643
```

3. listo. intentar instalar el programa nuevamente.